# Associated entities with onDelete: CASCADE option and both soft-deleteable not working

Tags: symfony

everyone!

i have two associated entities(User,Picture) with cascade="remove" option and both soft-deleteable

When I use softdelete to delete a user, should put the pictures were deleted.and now it's not working.

without softdelete everything works perfect.

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

my code:

Picture.orm.yml

```
Leo\TestBundle\Entity\Picture:
type: entity
repositoryClass: Leo\TestBundle\Entity\PictureRepository
table: null
manyToOne:
   user:
       targetEntity: User
       inversedBy: pictures
       joinColumn:
           name: user_id
           referencedColumnName: id
           onDelete: CASCADE
gedmo:
    soft_deleteable:
      field_name: deletedAt
fields:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
    name:
        type: string
        length: 255
    path:
        type: string
        length: 255
    deletedAt:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
```

User.orm.yml:

```
Leo\TestBundle\Entity\User:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: Leo\TestBundle\Entity\UserRepository
oneToMany:
    pictures:
        targetEntity: Picture
        mappedBy: user
gedmo:
    soft_deleteable:
      field_name: deletedAt
fields:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
    username:
        type: string
        length: 255
    email:
        type: string
        length: 255
    password:
        type: string
        length: 255
    sex:
        type: integer
    bloodtype:
        type: string
        length: 10
    birthday:
        type: date
    pr:
        type: text
    salt:
        type: string
        length: 255
    deletedAt:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

app/config/config.yml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
```

action

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    $token = $this->getRequest()->get('token');
    if (! $this->get('form.csrf_provider')->isCsrfTokenValid('user_list', $token)) {
        //TODO use setFlashBag
        $this->get('session')->setFlash('notice', 'Woops! Token invalid!');
        return $this->redirect('user_list');
    }
    //$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $pictures = $user->getPictures();
    $em->remove($user);
    /* foreach( $pictures as $p ){
        unlink($p->getAbsolutePath());
    } */
    $em->flush();
    $this->get('security.context')->setToken(null);
    $this->getRequest()
         ->getSession()
         ->invalidate();
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('leo_test_homepage'));
}
```

`

Comment: Is the cascade option present in your database?

Comment: no! forgive me, i am not really understand what's your mean..

Comment: Adding it to your code is not enough. Did you run the doctrine:schema:update --force command? Or did you manually add the cascade on your database?

Comment: i am 100% sure have run the doctrine:schema:update --force command, without softdeleteable, cascade work fine. when i add softdelete operation, the problem came out. did i missed something important?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, The problem was finally found out.Is my carelessness.

```
Leo\TestBundle\Entity\Picture:
type: entity
repositoryClass: Leo\TestBundle\Entity\PictureRepository
table: null
manyToOne:
   user:
       targetEntity: User
       inversedBy: pictures
       joinColumn:
           name: user_id
           referencedColumnName: id
           #**Comment out the line of code**
           #onDelete: CASCADE
gedmo:
    soft_deleteable:
      field_name: deletedAt
```

User entity

```
Leo\TestBundle\Entity\User:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: Leo\TestBundle\Entity\UserRepository
oneToMany:
    pictures:
        targetEntity: Picture
        mappedBy: user
        # add cascade option here
        cascade: [persist, remove]
gedmo:
    soft_deleteable:
      field_name: deletedAt
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your question, it's helpful to others :) I hate when people just post "nevermind I solved it" :)

Comment: Also, I faced with a problem that If you set cascade operation "remove" to a dependent relation and not to set in the main relation - doctrine intent to hard delete the main relation. In case if both entities have soft delete configs.

To fix this just set cascade: remove to a "parent" relation (in my case it was one to many).

Comment: I face a second time with such a problem, but from another side: all the settings are correct, but it tries to delete at all. The reason could be also that entity which you intend to delete is not **initialized** and when you removed it and some listener onFlush event tries to get the whole object (my case LoggableListener) it put a EM status **managed** instead of "removed". That's why you can see in doctrine WebProfiler 2 SQL queries: one which correct (update), and one which tries to delete it with DELETE statement. So just need to initialize somehow. Hope it will be helpful for somebody :)